# How to explode a string on a hyphen in Java?

Tags: java, string, arraylist, replace

I have a task which involves me creating a program that reads text from a text file, and from that produces a word count, and lists the occurrence of each word used in the file. I managed to remove punctuation from the word count but I'm really stumped on this:

I want java to see this string "hello-funny-world" as 3 separate strings and store them in my array list, this is what I have so far , with this section of code I having issues , I just get "hello funny world" seen as one string:

```
while (reader.hasNext()){

            String nextword2 = reader.next();

            String nextWord3 = nextword2.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z0-9'-]", "");
            String nextWord = nextWord3.replace("-", " ");

            int apcount = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < nextWord.length(); i++){
                if (nextWord.charAt(i)== 39){
                apcount++;
            }
            }

            int i = nextWord.length() - apcount;


            if (wordlist.contains(nextWord)){
                int index = wordlist.indexOf(nextWord);
                count.set(index, count.get(index) + 1);

            }
            else{
                wordlist.add(nextWord);
                count.add(1);
                if (i / 2 * 2 == i){
                    wordlisteven.add(nextWord);
                }
                else{
                    wordlistodd.add(nextWord);
                }
            }
```

Comment: You can just use `String#split()`, you will get an array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can work for you ....

`List<String> items = Arrays.asList("hello-funny-world".split("-"));`

Comment: this makes sense thanks! is there a way to make this apply to all strings that contain a hyphen ?

Comment: Yep. You can use split all String like that

Answer (score 0):

By considering that you are using the separator as '-'

> I would suggest you to use simple **split()** of java

```
String name="this-is-string";
String arr[]=name.split("-");
System.out.println("Here " +arr.length);
```

Also you will be able to iterate through this array using **for()** loop

Hope this helps.